# Assigning characters of array data members

Tags: visual-c++

What is the best way to assign a char of array data member in class?

i tried using this

```
   void setName(char a[]) {
      strcpy(name, a);
   }
```

but it gives me an error of

strcpy is unsafe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this might lead to a buffer overflow!

One solution might be avoiding `strcpy()`.

Instead, use string that C++ already has!

```
void setName(char a[]) {
        std::string a_str = a;
        name = a_str;
}
```

**Note:** Do not forget to define name as following:

```
std::string name;
```

Comment: but what if the character has a white space on it? lets say like "new york" how can i copy the whole string including the white space?

Comment: It does not matter, the assigment from char array to string also includes whitespaces! Give it a chance and try now :)

Comment: Thank you so much i will surely try it :)

Comment: i believe it works just having trouble with the getting the string name from the class. i just made a getter string getName { return name} but when i try to use it gives me an error 'string differs in level of indirection  from char[100]

Comment: define everything as std::string, also char[100]

Comment: im sorry im not sure i understand? like set the function to std:: string getname()

Comment: no, i mean do not use char arrays. use `string` for all. not use char[100]  replace it with string

Comment: its still giving me an error. The code where the error is in this line std::string getNameFromInv= inv.getName(id); ///// the function goes like                        
string getName(int id) {
  for (int i=0; i < a.size(); i++) {
   if (a[i].id == id) {
    return a[i].name;
   }
  }
 }

Comment: nvm i found the error! thank you so much for all the Help! :)

Comment: Yeyyy ! Please accept answer by clicking tick next to it!